# Power Bi dax measure help: tips on ignoring a slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working in Power BI and I created a DAX measure that adds up two other DAX measures.

For one measure I need it to ignore the month slicer because I need the total for that category. Is it possible to do so?

Also, is it possible for it to ignore the slicer and still give me the total for unfiltered DAX measure + the date filter DAX measure?

DAX code:

```
Monthly Total Act = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'sheet1'[Amount] ),
    FILTER ( 'sheet1', 'sheet1'[Type] = "ACT" ),
    FILTER ( 'sheet1', 'sheet1'[Bill] = "Y" )`
)
```

```
Monthly Total of Acs = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'sheet1'[Amount] ),
    FILTER ( 'sheet1', 'sheet1'[Type] = "ACR" ),
    FILTER ( 'sheet1', 'sheet1'[Bill] = "Y" )`
)
```

Adding these two formulas together to get the total monthly.

The monthly total of `ACS` is where I encounter the problem. I need this to be unaffected by the slicer

The end goal is having the month total of `ACS` unaffected by the data slicer and add to the monthly total of `Act` that requires filter by the current month.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add this line as a third filter argument in the calculat function you want to ignore the month slicer:

```
ALL('tableName'[monthColumnUsedAsSlicer])
```

Then the monthe slicer will not affect calculations.

Comment: will this work even if the month slicer is in a different table?

Comment: If you have a relationship between the two tables then yes. If you dont the slicer wont work anyway... :)